# Shopify: Send customer to a page after registration

Tags: shopify

I have a shopify store and I want the customer to go directly to the product page when registering.

I changed the customers/register.liquid file and it does what I want, but now it doesn't check if the password is valid or if the user exists.

What's the problem? several times the customer enters an invalid password but my code sends him to the product page, the customer makes try to make a purchase but shopify asks for the login, the customer enters the login and gives an error, because in reality shopify does not registered it and the customer does not exist, but my code is passing to the product page

I add this code to shopify (line 15)

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="/products/healthy-box"/>
```

my code final code is

```
<section
  class="customer login page"
  data-section-id="{{ section.id }}"
  data-section-type="register"
>
  <div class="login__inner page__inner">
    <header style="margin-bottom:40px;" class="login__header page__header">
      <h1 class="login__heading article__heading ff-heading fs-heading-2-large fs-heading-1-base-ns ta-c">{{ 'customer.register.title' | t }}</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="login__main">

      {%- assign formId = 'RegisterForm' -%}
      {% form 'create_customer', id: formId, novalidate: 'novalidate' %}
      <input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="/products/healthy-box"/>

      
        {%- assign success_msg = 'customer.register.success' | t -%}
        {%- render 'form-status', form: form, form_id: formId, success_message: success_msg -%}

        <label for="{{ formId }}-FirstName" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="customer[first_name]"
          placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}"
          id="{{ formId }}-FirstName"
          class="input"
          {% if form.first_name %}value="{{ form.first_name }}"{% endif %}
          autocomplete="given-name"
        >

        <label for="{{ formId }}-LastName" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="customer[last_name]"
          placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}"
          id="{{ formId }}-LastName"
          class="input"
          {% if form.last_name %}value="{{ form.last_name }}"{% endif %}
          autocomplete="family-name"
        >

        <label for="{{ formId }}-email" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="customer[email]"
          placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}"
          id="{{ formId }}-email"
          class="input {% if form.errors contains 'email' %} input--error{% endif %}"
          {% if form.email %} value="{{ form.email }}"{% endif %}
          autocorrect="off"
          autocapitalize="off"
          autocomplete="email"
          aria-required="true"
          {%- if form.errors contains 'email' -%}
            class="input--error"
            aria-invalid="true"
            aria-describedby="{{ formId }}-email-error"
          {%- endif -%}
        >

        <label for="{{ formId }}-password" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="customer[password]"
          placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}"
          id="{{ formId }}-password"
          class="input {% if form.errors contains 'password' %} input--error{% endif %}"
          aria-required="true"
          {%- if form.errors contains 'password' -%}
            class="input--error"
            aria-invalid="true"
            aria-describedby="{{ formId }}-password-error"
          {%- endif -%}
        >

<p style="margin-bottom:20px;font-size:18px;">Your password needs to be at least 6 characters long.</p>
      
        <input
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn--primary btn--medium"
          value="{{ 'customer.register.submit' | t }}"
        >

      {% endform %}
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried also added this second code after {% endform %}

```
{% if form.posted_successfully? %}
  {% assign redirect_url = '/products/oh-my-snacks-box' %}
  {% if customer %}
    <script>
      window.location.href = '{{ redirect_url }}';
    </script>
  {% else %}
    <script>
      window.location.href = '/products/healthy-box';
    </script>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

But the result is the same.

If I remove

the shopify send the customer to home page

Thanks for your time and help.
Ric

My final code with Onkar input is

```
<section
      class="customer login page"
      data-section-id="{{ section.id }}"
      data-section-type="register"
    >
      <div class="login__inner page__inner">
        <header style="margin-bottom:40px;" class="login__header page__header">
          <h1 class="login__heading article__heading ff-heading fs-heading-2-large fs-heading-1-base-ns ta-c">{{ 'customer.register.title' | t }}</h1>
        </header>
    
        <div class="login__main">
    
          {%- assign formId = 'RegisterForm' -%}
          {% form 'create_customer', id: formId, novalidate: 'novalidate' %}    
          <input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="/products/snacks-box"/>
            {%- assign success_msg = 'customer.register.success' | t -%}
            {%- render 'form-status', form: form, form_id: formId, success_message: success_msg -%}
    
            <label for="{{ formId }}-FirstName" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="customer[first_name]"
              placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}"
              id="{{ formId }}-FirstName"
              class="input"
              {% if form.first_name %}value="{{ form.first_name }}"{% endif %}
              autocomplete="given-name"
            >
    
            <label for="{{ formId }}-LastName" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="customer[last_name]"
              placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}"
              id="{{ formId }}-LastName"
              class="input"
              {% if form.last_name %}value="{{ form.last_name }}"{% endif %}
              autocomplete="family-name"
            >
    
            <label for="{{ formId }}-email" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              name="customer[email]"
              placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}"
              id="{{ formId }}-email"
              class="input {% if form.errors contains 'email' %} input--error{% endif %}"
              {% if form.email %} value="{{ form.email }}"{% endif %}
              autocorrect="off"
              autocapitalize="off"
              autocomplete="email"
              aria-required="true"
              {%- if form.errors contains 'email' -%}
                class="input--error"
                aria-invalid="true"
                aria-describedby="{{ formId }}-email-error"
              {%- endif -%}
            >
    
            <label for="{{ formId }}-password" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              name="customer[password]"
              placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}"
              id="{{ formId }}-password"
              class="input {% if form.errors contains 'password' %} input--error{% endif %}"
              aria-required="true"
              {%- if form.errors contains 'password' -%}
                class="input--error"
                aria-invalid="true"
                aria-describedby="{{ formId }}-password-error"
              {%- endif -%}
            >
    
    <p style="margin-bottom:20px;font-size:18px;">Your password needs to be at least 6 characters long.</p>
          
            <input
              type="submit"
              class="btn btn--primary btn--medium"
              value="{{ 'customer.register.submit' | t }}"
            >
    
          {% endform %}

          {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
            {% assign redirect_url = '/products/snacks-box' %}
              {% if customer %}
                <script>
                  window.location.href = '{{ redirect_url }}';
                </script>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: why the else also have redirect, use only `{% if %}` so register is successful then it redirect otherwise not.

Comment: Thanks Onkar. I changed the code but now did not verify if the password is valid. I edit my final code in my question with your output

Comment: remove the return_to input hidden fields from the code also, it send you too given URL.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/mC3RWCDuFujz

Comment: If I do that and remove the line, it checks that the password is valid, but then sends me to the homepage and not the product page. I do not understand why...

Comment: is there challenge on customer registration is on?

Comment: I don't now if I understood. Do you mean challenge to verify if the customer is a human? If Yes, we don't verify

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252222/discussion-between-onkar-and-kardu).